# QueryString encoding of non-ANSI characters in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ansi, utf-8

I'm passing "Malmö" as a Request.QueryString parameter to a page. However, the code sees it as "Malm�" meaning that string comparison fails. All globalization settings are set to UTF-8 in web.config. Am I missing something?

Edit: The querystring looks like this http://localhost/PageName/?courseKommun=Malm%F6

Comment: Have you tried to encode the parameter with HttpUtility.UrlEncode("Malmö") ?

Answer (score 0):

**`%F6`** is not the URL encoding for **ö**, that's why you don't see an **ö**.
The correct URL encoding would be **`%C3%B6`** ([see](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/)).

It should work just fine with both versions:

- `/?courseKommun=Malmö`
- `/?courseKommun=Malm%C3%B6`